# Adding a line break in the title attribute

Tags: html

i would like to find out how to add a break in the title attribute, i would like to have breaks in the title attribute to differentiate the names.
how can i add a break in the title attribute?

i have something like this

```
<p title="this is a description of the some text <br> and further description">Some Text</p>
```

what comes out is:[image: image showing <br> in stead of braking.]

Comment: The title is plain text. It does not render HTML tags.

Comment: You could possibly use some external tool like the [Jquery UI tooltip](http://jqueryui.com/tooltip/)

Comment: @Robusto, it's actually confusing. The title does not represent the code example. I think he means the title **attribute**, based on the example, updated to clarify

Comment: @Liam: You're right. In that case, voting to close as dupe.

Comment: Just use the entity code &#013; for a linebreak in a title attribute.

Comment: @Aliti : Thanks a lot, works like a charm.

Answer (score 10):

If you add a new line where you want line breaks, it works on SOME browsers, but not all.

Example:

```css
div { background-color: #c3c3c3; display: block; width: 100px; height: 100px; }
```

```html
<div title="This is a text
    Second line
    Third line!">Contents</div>
```

JSFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/g5CGh/

Comment: Tested and works with:
Firefox 42, Opera 39, IE11
please add comment if there is any browser that doesn't work

Comment: this has always worked (where title was supported), early HTML documentation did a similar thing with the alt tag.

Answer (score 6):

In the title text replace `<br>` for `&lt;br /&gt;`

```
<p title="this is a description of the some text &lt;br /&gt; and further description">Some Text</p>
```

And now replace `<br />` with a line break `\n` (jquery):

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $('p').each(function(){
        var a = $(this).attr('title');
        var b = a.replace('<br />','\n');
        $(this).attr('title', b);
    });
    });
</script>
```

Hope I've helped you

Comment: Or you may Add "\n" in your title wherever you want a line-break.

Comment: it s not necessary to use "\n" in my case